# git add . does not add to the stage to commit

Tags: git

I tried to add all files, but am not able to add files. What do I need to do?

```
➜  dotfiles git:(master) git add .
➜  dotfiles git:(master) git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   .vim/bundle/ultisnips (untracked content)
#   modified:   .vim/bundle/ultisnips-rspec (modified content)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

UPDATE: my .gitignore

```
# Compiled source #
###################
*.com
*.class
*.dll
*.exe
*.o
*.so

# Packages #
############
# it's better to unpack these files and commit the raw source
# git has its own built in compression methods
*.7z
*.dmg
*.gz
*.iso
*.jar
*.rar
*.tar
*.zip

# Logs and databases #
######################
*.log
*.sql
*.sqlite

# OS generated files #
######################
.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
ehthumbs.db
Thumbs.db

# other files #
#####################
*.swp
*.swo

# git mergetool #
*.orig
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your changes seem to be in submodules. As the output of `git status` hints, you have to add and commit changes in submodules inside the submodules, for example:

```
cd .vim/bundle
git add .
git status
```